# jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError:

Tags: html, python, flask

Al momento de correr una página hecha con Flask y Python, me arroja este error:

[image: Error Jinga debug=True]

> jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Unexpected end of template. Jinja was looking for the following tags: 'endblock'. The innermost block that needs to be closed is 'block'.

Ya intenté hacer lo que dicen todas las demás páginas (probar eliminando el espacio entre los %%) pero tampoco se resuelve.

Comment: No olvides mostrar un [repro].